# space in css div won't go away

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get rid of some space that keeps getting appended to the front of my main text div... i'm guessing I have a missing property in my css...  Wondering how to fix it...it kind of looks like its setting the top of the "main" div to the bottom of the "docmap" div.

[image]

here's by css:

```
#docmap {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; 
}
#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: 200px; 
  padding: 20px;
}
```

here's by html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../js/load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="docmap"></div>
<div id="main"><pre>
<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit above
<!----------------------------------------------->

<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

$$\delta(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & n = 0 \\
0 & otherwise 
\end{cases}
$$

<h2>Jabberwocky 1</h2>
</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well this - `position: 200px;` is doing *nothing* - but the first thing I would suggest is to zero out all margins. Then set the `main` div to `display:inline-block`

Comment: Get rid of these comments too .
<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit above
<!----------------------------------------------->

Inside <pre> these are occupying space too.

Comment: I suggest you to check it using the brower's dev tools, it may be a lot easier to know which element is adding that space (because in some cases, it's something with the browser's default styling on elements).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<pre></pre>` wrapper  and comment

Comment: ohh!.... maybe i can delete the front padding using javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is a misplaced `<pre>` tag. The `<pre>` tag in `<div id="main"><pre>` has a comment inside along with an extra newline. That shows up in the HTML file and causes an extra space. Move it below the comment and everything works out fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's the content within the `<pre>` tag.

Remove the comments and spacing between the `<pre>` and `<h1>`. Then you'll just have to contend with the default top and bottom margin on the `<pre>`.

If you are unable to do that for whatever reason, simply use CSS with `white-space: normal;` on the `<pre>`. e.g `pre { white-space: normal; }`

Answer (score 1):

The comment in the preformatted text (`<pre>` element) is taking up space. Move or remove it. Additionally the `h1` has a margin-top by default. Remove it. Furthermore, remove the top padding in `#main`:

```css
#docmap {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; 
}
#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 0 20px; <-- removed top and bottom padding, kept 20px left and right -->
}
#main h1 {
  margin-top:0; <-- overwrote the default top margin -->
}
```

```html
<div id="docmap"></div>
<div id="main"><pre>
<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

$$\delta(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & n = 0 \\
0 & otherwise 
\end{cases}
$$

<h2>Jabberwocky 1</h2>
</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the default margin of the H1 header:

```
h1 { margin-top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#docmap {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; 
}
#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
 padding-top: 0;
}

pre {
 margin: 0;
white-space: normal;   
 
}

#main h1 {
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="docmap"></div>
<div id="main"><pre>
<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit above
<!----------------------------------------------->

<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

$$\delta(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & n = 0 \\
0 & otherwise 
\end{cases}
$$

<h2>Jabberwocky 1</h2>
</pre>
</div>
```

Keeping your existing HTML, you can set `white-space: normal` on the `pre` element to remove it's internal spacing.

(I've also removed additional margins and padding)