# find the first pre tag in a div and then delete the leading white spaces

Tags: javascript, html

How can i use javascript jquery to find the div tag "main", and then from this div tag check if the first element that exists is a pre tag, and if it is a pre tag, then delete the leading white spaces?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../js/load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="docmap"></div>
<div id="main"><pre>
<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit above
<!----------------------------------------------->

<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm thinking it needs to be something like this:

```
    var main   = $("#main");
    var pre  = main.find("pre");
    pre[0].htmlInner.textContent.replace(/^\s+/mg, "");
    //main.children("pre")[0].htmlInner.textContent.replace(/^\s+/mg, "")
```

Comment: Are you aware that [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) are preferred over `var`? … and you can use the [main](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) element instead of `<div id="main">` — `main` is [supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic)

Comment: Just FYI, that HTML is invalid. The second comment starts on the second line in the `pre` and ends at the end of the **third** line of the `pre` and contains the invalid sequence `<!--`, [more here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#comments). (Probably there was supposed to be a `-->` at the end of the second line.)

Answer (score 3):

That approach won't work because of the HTML comment in the block. If the comments weren't there, your code wouldn't be far off, but:

1. It's [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), not `htmlInner`
2. You have to assign the result of `replace`, it doesn't modify the string you call it on (more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work)'s answers)

But that approach also has the problem that if you have any event handlers on anything in that `pre` element, they'll get removed by assigning to `innerHTML`.

But we need to handle the comment nodes, which means it's a *tiny* bit more complicated; see comments:

```
// Start with the first child of the `pre`
let node = document.querySelector("#main pre").firstChild;
// Stop when we run out of nodes or find the first element node
while (node && node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    const next = node.nextSibling;
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // Text node, remove leading whitespace
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.trimStart();
        if (node.nodeValue) {
            // Non-empty text node after trimming; stop
            break;
        } else {
            // Empty text node, remove
            node.remove();
        }
    }
    node = next;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// Start with the first child of the `pre`
let node = document.querySelector("#main pre").firstChild;
// Stop when we run out of nodes or find the first element node
while (node && node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    const next = node.nextSibling;
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // Text node, remove leading whitespace
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.trimStart();
        if (node.nodeValue) {
            // Non-empty text node after trimming; stop
            break;
        } else {
            // Empty text node, remove
            node.remove();
        }
    }
    node = next;
}
```

```html
<div id="docmap"></div>
<div id="main"><pre>
<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit above
<!----------------------------------------------->

<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
</pre>
</div>
```

That code assumes a modern browser, it won't work on IE11. If you need to support IE11, we have to remove any ES2015+ stuff (`let`, `const`, `trimStart`) and use `removeChild` rather than the newer `remove`:

```
// Start with the first child of the `pre`
var node = document.querySelector("#main pre").firstChild;
// Stop when we run out of nodes or find the first element node
while (node && node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    var next = node.nextSibling;
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // Text node, remove leading whitespace
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+/g, ""); // No need for the `g` flag
        if (node.nodeValue) {
            // Non-empty text node after trimming; stop
            break;
        } else {
            // Empty text node, remove
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
    }
    node = next;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// Start with the first child of the `pre`
var node = document.querySelector("#main pre").firstChild;
// Stop when we run out of nodes or find the first element node
while (node && node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    var next = node.nextSibling;
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // Text node, remove leading whitespace
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+/g, ""); // No need for the `g` flag
        if (node.nodeValue) {
            // Non-empty text node after trimming; stop
            break;
        } else {
            // Empty text node, remove
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
    }
    node = next;
}
```

```html
<div id="docmap"></div>
<div id="main"><pre>
<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit above
<!----------------------------------------------->

<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
</pre>
</div>
```

That works all the way back to IE9. (It would work in IE8 if you replaced `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` with `1` and `Node.TEXT_NODE` with `3`.)

Comment: I think the HTML comments within the `pre` still cause an issue. In a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60062254/1921385) this OP is looking to remove all the white-space above the poem. Some of this white-space is caused by the comments which are not removed in this solution. Granted, this solution does meet the OP's requirements as stated so you get my upvote anyway.

Comment: @Moob - Thanks! I don't recall the HTML being in the question, so didn't see the comment nodes at the beginning of the `pre`. (Either it was a ninja edit in the first five minutes, or I was **really** not paying attention.) Fixed. Thanks again for the head's up!

Comment: @StephenP - *"Does assigning to `innerText` rather than `innerHTML` also remove event handlers?"* Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Merely removing leading whitespace won't correct for the space at the top of your `pre` that is being created by the html comments. This simple function (not my own) will remove comments and whitespace-only text nodes.

```js
var pre = document.querySelector("#main pre");

//The following is not my code! 
//Author: James Edwards
//See: https://www.sitepoint.com/removing-useless-nodes-from-the-dom/
function clean(node) {
  for (var n = 0; n < node.childNodes.length; n++) {
    var child = node.childNodes[n];
    if (
      child.nodeType === 8 ||
      (child.nodeType === 3 && !/\S/.test(child.nodeValue))
    ) {
      node.removeChild(child);
      n--;
    } else if (child.nodeType === 1) {
      clean(child);
    }
  }
}

clean(pre);
```

```html
<div id="docmap"></div>
<div id="main">
  <pre>
<!----------------------------------------------->
<!-- do not edit above
<!----------------------------------------------->

<h1>Jabberwocky 1</h1>
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth (?) noting that one can use the more readable `Node.COMMENT_NODE` etc constants to get rid of the magic numbers 8, 3, 1